# What is the use of Multiple Inheritance in languages like C++ and Python?

Tags: c++, python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

C++ and Python are the only two languages I know supporting multiple Inheritance. Other object oriented languages I have seen like Java and Ruby do not support multiple inheritance. Even the front-end scripting languages do not support multiple inheritance.
According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance),

> Multiple inheritance allows programmers to use more than one totally orthogonal hierarchy simultaneously, such as allowing Cat to inherit from Cartoon character and Pet and Mammal and access features from within all of those classes.

Inheritance follows the protocol: "A is a B". In reality, we usually do not see any circumstances where "A" can be "B" and "A" can be "C". For example, a laptop is a computer and a smartphone is a telephone. But in reality, there is nothing that can be both a computer and a telephone. What is the use of more than one totally orthogonal hierarchy simultaneously?

Comment: Consider that Java has interfaces, whereas Python and C++ use normal inheritance for equivalent purposes. It is normal for a class to implement multiple interfaces. With default methods in interfaces, Java even eventually provided a kind of multiple inheritance as well!

Comment: "*But in reality, there is nothing that can be both a computer and a telephone*" Nonsense. I'm carrying one in my pocket as we speak. There is no reasonable definition of "computer" that would exclude my smartphone, and there is no reasonable definition of "telephone" that would exclude my smartphone.

Comment: Sometimes the same object is a different thing to different clients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While one could justify multiple inheritance via appeals to some philosophical aspects of OOP (for example, pointing out that there are a multitude of devices that can legitimately be considered both "telephones" and "computers" by any reasonable definition of those terms), when it comes to C++ in particular, there is a far stronger argument to be made.

Inheritance is not merely a philosophical construct; it is a *mechanism* provided by a programming language. And language mechanisms can be used to accomplish various tasks. Specifically, inheritance in C++ is pretty much the only way for a class to have methods and functionality injected into it from the outside.

For example, let's say you have a construct like `std::shared_ptr<T>`. This is a template class that represents ownership of a `T` from multiple holders. One thing that can sometimes be useful is the ability to convert a pointer/reference to a `T` which is owned by a `shared_ptr<T>` into a `shared_ptr`. That is, someone gave you a pointer/reference and you now want to claim (shared) ownership through that pointer/reference.

Now if that's going to work, `T` clearly need to know that this is possible, since you need to call an interface function of `T` to do it. But `T` needs more than to just know that this is possible. When a `shared_ptr<T>` is constructed, it creates a storage block which manages the lifetime of the object. In order for `T` to have an interface to claim ownership of itself, it needs to have access to this storage block. Which means that `shared_ptr`'s constructor needs to hook into the `T` it is being wrapped around so that it can deposit a pointer of some sort to this storage block.

So... how does that work? Simple: inherit from a base class. The `shared_ptr` constructor can use basic metaprogramming to detect if `T` is derived from this base class, and then use a private API to do its business to it. Specifically, the type `T` must inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this<T>`.

And yes, I didn't write that incorrectly: `T` must inherit from a base class that is templated *on `T` itself*. Indeed, this trick (inheriting from a base class that's templated on the derived class name) is so common that it has a name: the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern.

This is a mechanism for implementing a form of mixin functionality in C++. You can bundle common functionality into a base class, and through the magic of templates, you can use the derived class name (despite it not having yet been properly *defined*) in certain specific ways that allow you to call derived class functions from base class functions.

This is done because inheritance is the *only tool* C++ has for affecting a class's member interface from outside of the class.

Here's the thing, though. There is no reason whatsoever that `enable_shared_from_this<T>` cannot coexist with some other CRTP base class functionality. There's no reason why a type could not enable shared from this and enable some other functionality. As long as the mixins do not collide in terms of interfaces, they're fine, because basically nobody is *directly* using the base class itself.

Without multiple inheritance, using multiple CRTP mixins would not be possible.

Comment: That's surely an interesting use case for MI. However, I am pretty sure MI as a language feature was not provided in C++ specifically for template meta programming, since MI was part of the language right from the beginning ~1984, but template meta programming became popular at least one or two decades later. So I think there should exist a far more simpler example.

Comment: @DocBrown: It probably wasn't. But the OP didn't ask for historical reasons for why the feature was added to the language. They asked "what is the use" of it.

Comment: I guess I did not make point clear, so let my try again. For every feature of a language like C++ must be certain use cases at the time when the feature was introduced into the language, Stroustrup did not add anything "just for fun" into C++. That we can find a lot more (and more complex) use cases at a point in time 10-20 years later is not really astonishing, but there should by a more fundamental justification for such a feature.

Comment: @DocBrown, the strongest justification that I could find is that the feature is needed for creating a class that implements multiple interfaces. Another motivation that I found was that Stroustrup was challenged that it could not be implemented and he wanted to prove the challenger wrong.

Comment: The "classic" C++ MI scenario is `std::iostream`; maybe that's a better example to use here as that's been in C++ since "Day 1" (or at least the 1990s).

Comment: @PhilipKendall: yes, that looks like the kind of example I was looking for. As  a side note, it seems I was not accurate about the history: according to this site https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/history , MI was indeed not part of the initial C++, but introduced in 1989. Templates were added in 1990, and the first STL in 1992.

Comment: CRTP is for mixins that are generic, but you don't need it if your mixin is specific, e.g. making an ["overload set" function object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit#Example)